# NavigableMap vs. SortedMap?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

Is there any reason to use [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) instead of [`NavigableMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), besides the JVM version? (`NavigableMap` has only been there since 1.6; `SortedMap` has been there since 1.2)

I'm trying to find the value with the greatest key such that key <= reference key K0. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with a `SortedMap` (if it were strictly <, then I'd call `headMap()` and then `lastKey()` and then `get()`), but [`NavigableMap.floorEntry()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) seems to be exactly what I need.

---

**clarification:** just as an example, I'm handling sparse ranges of version numbers with different behavior models. The keys might be [0, 2, 5], so that version numbers 0 and 1 get handled by the value at key #0, version numbers 2-4 get handled by the value at key #2, and version numbers >= 5 get handled by the value at key #5.

Comment: [According to Josh Bloch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw#t=1258), the author of both interfaces, there are flaws in SortedMap, which were fixed in Java 6 by introducing NavigableMap.

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I'm a big believer in using the least specific interface that provides you with what you need. This makes your intentions clearer and places less restrictions on your possible implementations.

Most developers want Sorted collections for iteration purposes and perhaps for random access performance. I've seen very few cases where I needed a close element.

If you need that functionality, go ahead. I think that TreeMap actually implements NavigableMap. But when you don't need it, why restrict yourself?

Comment: for me I needed (and expected) SortedMap.keySet() to return a SortedSet, I was surprised that it didn't.. it returns a Set.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any reason to use SortedMap instead of NavigableMap, besides the JVM version?

Yes I can think of one example.  The provider of the map may have wrapped it with `Collections.unmodifiableSortedMap`, so even if the source was a `TreeMap` (which implements `NavigableMap`) you only have a reference to a `SortedMap` and you cannot cast it to `NavigableMap`.

> I'm trying to find the value with the greatest key such that key <= reference key K0. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with a SortedMap

Well there are two cases: either the map contains an exact match for the key or it does not.  So first look for an exact match and only if it does not exist then `m.headMap(key).lastKey()` will give the right answer.

---

This will do it (though it is not as efficient as a real `NavigableMap`):

```
static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V> floorEntry(final SortedMap<K, V> m, K key) {
    final SortedMap<K, V> tail; 
    if (m.containsKey(key)) {
        tail = m.tailMap(key);
    } else {
        SortedMap<K, V> head = m.headMap(key);
        if (head.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            tail = head.tailMap(head.lastKey());
        }
    }
    return tail.entrySet()
               .iterator()
               .next();
}
```

Comment: I know that I'm necroposting on a 12+ years old answer, but, if jyou are reading this answer in 2023+, `Collections.unmodifiableNavigableMap` has been added to Java a long time ago (Java 8): https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableNavigableMap(java.util.NavigableMap)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any reason to use `SortedMap` instead of `NavigableMap`, besides the JVM version?

**Yes, if you need to return an unmodifiable map on Java 7 or earlier and you are not using Google Guava.**

`NavigableMap` is intended to supersede `SortedMap`.  `NavigableMap` adds methods to the `SortedMap` interface that are needed quite often, are easy to for a `Map` implementer to add, but are awkward to write in terms of existing `SortedMap` methods.  Returning `SortedMap` instead of `NavigableMap` will cause callers of your code unnecessary work.

It's unfortunate that `Collections.unmodifiableNavigableMap` was not provided.  IMO this was likely an oversight, but it wasn't rectified in JDK 1.7 so maybe someone had a reason to leave it out.    It was added in Java 8, however.  I suggest using [`com.google.common.collect.Maps.unmodifiableNavigableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#unmodifiableNavigableMap%28java.util.NavigableMap%29).

Answer (score 3):

When working with integers you can use x < A+1 instead of x <= A and you're done. I mean headMap(A+1), etc., should do the job. Otherwise, I'd go for finnw's solution since it's more clear than anything I can come out with.

Answer (score 3):

I think that using Iterators is better than using headMap and tailMap, because it is not efficient. I tested the following code for cases and it works good and floorEntry2 is three times faster than floorEntry1.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


class TestMapUtils <K,V> {

    public TestMapUtils()
    {

    }

    public Map.Entry<K, V> floorEntry1(final SortedMap<K, V> m, K key) {
        final SortedMap<K, V> tail; 
        if (m.containsKey(key)) {
            tail = m.tailMap(key);
        } else {
            SortedMap<K, V> head = m.headMap(key);
            if (head.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                tail = head.tailMap(head.lastKey());
            }
        }
        return tail.entrySet()
                   .iterator()
                   .next();
    }

    public Map.Entry<K, V> floorEntry2(final NavigableMap<K, V> m, K key) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> i = m.entrySet().iterator();
        Entry<K,V> tailEntry = null;
        if (key==null) {
            while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            if (e.getKey()==null)
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
                if (key.equals(e.getKey()))
                {
                    return e;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (((Integer) e.getKey()).intValue() < (((Integer) key).intValue())) {
                        tailEntry = e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tailEntry;
    }
}

public class TestSortedMap {

    protected TestMapUtils<Integer, Integer> testMapUtils;
    private NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> sortedMap;
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        testMapUtils = new TestMapUtils<Integer, Integer>();
        sortedMap = addElementsToMap();
    }

    private NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> addElementsToMap() {
        NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        map.put(10, 1);
        map.put(20, 2);
        map.put(30, 3);
        map.put(40, 4);
        map.put(50, 5);
        map.put(60, 6);
        return map;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFloorEntry()
    {

        long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();

        Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry2(sortedMap, 30);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 30);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry2(sortedMap, 60);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 60);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry2(sortedMap, 70);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 60);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry2(sortedMap, 55);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 50);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry2(sortedMap, 31);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 30);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry2(sortedMap, 0);
        assertNull(entry);



        long endTime1 = System.nanoTime() - startTime1;

        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry1(sortedMap, 30);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 30);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry1(sortedMap, 60);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 60);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry1(sortedMap, 70);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 60);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry1(sortedMap, 55);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 50);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry1(sortedMap, 31);
        assertNotNull(entry);
        assertEquals(entry.getKey().intValue(), 30);

        entry = testMapUtils.floorEntry1(sortedMap, 0);
        assertNull(entry);

        long endTime2 = System.nanoTime() - startTime2;

        if ( endTime2 > endTime1 )
        {
            System.out.println("First Execution is faster.. "+endTime1+", "+endTime2);
        } else if ( endTime1 > endTime2 ) {

            System.out.println("Second Execution is faster.. "+endTime1+", "+endTime2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Execution times are same");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"[NavigableMap] is intended to supersede the SortedMap interface." 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes6.html

Despite this, I agree with Uri: use the least specific interface you can.